# Creating a box containing a picture

Tags: tables, tabularx

### Goal

I am trying to replicate creating the box under

[image]

[Taken from this link](https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4140/2017h/lf/LF01.pdf)

### Attempt

So far what I have managed to do is this

[image]

However my solution feels very hackish, the image is not in the correct position, the box is not properly centered and the lines are not propperly spaced. Is there a better way to produce a result similar to what was done above?

### Code

I think I used [this image](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1643456860/NTNU_logo_400x400.jpg) in my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ctable} % for \specialrule command
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X r|}
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em} \hline & \\

    \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{NTNU.png}} & \huge TMA4140 \\[0.2em] & \huge Diskre Matematikk \\[0.2em] & \huge Høst 2017 \\
    & \\ & \\ & \\
\large Norges teknisk-vitenskapelige & \\
\large universitet & \textbf{Løsningsforslag --- Øving 1}\\ 
\large Insitutt for matematiske fag & \\
\hline \specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em} 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some low level tricks (logo from Alenanno's answer):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}       
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{0,72,161}

\newcommand{\ntnulogo}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{
    \hrule height 0pt
    \hbox{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[mblue, rounded corners=5mm] (0,2) rectangle (2,4);
      \fill[white] (0.5,2.5) rectangle (1.5,3.5);
      \fill[mblue] (1,3) circle (4mm);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
  }
}
\newcommand{\course}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{\LARGE
    \hrule height 0pt
    \ialign{\hfil##\cr
      TMA4140 Diskret\cr
      Matematikk\cr
      Høst 2017\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule}
  \vspace{1pt}
  \hrule height 1pt
  \vspace{6pt}
  \mbox{}\quad\ntnulogo\hfill\course\quad\mbox{}\\[3pt]
  \mbox{}\quad
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Norges teknisk-vitenskapelige\\
  universitet\\
  Insitutt for matematiske fag
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \textbf{Løsningsforslag --- Øving 1}\quad\mbox{}\\
  \vspace{3pt}
  \hrule height1pt
  \vspace{1pt}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suppose there's more than one approach to do this, I love TikZ though so here's one solution using this package.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}       
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{0,72,161}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[mblue, rounded corners=5mm] (0,2) rectangle (2,4);
\fill[white] (0.5,2.5) rectangle (1.5,3.5);
\fill[mblue] (1,3) circle (4mm);

\node[outer sep=0, inner sep=0, anchor=north west, text width=12cm] (bt) at (0,1.8) {%
    Norges teknisk-vitenskapelige\\
    universitet\hfill\textbf{Løsningsforslag --- Øving 1}\\
    Insitutt for matematiske fag
};

\node[outer sep=0, inner sep=0, anchor=north east, text width=4cm, align=right, font=\Large] at (12,4) {%
    TMA4140 Diskret\\
    Matematikk\\
    Høst 2017
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks amazing! Any idea if it is possible to create the surrounding box in tikz as well?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Sure, you can add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` for some basic calculations, then name the last node `(tp)` and then add a line at the bottom: `\draw ($(bt.south west)+(-.5,-.5)$) rectangle ($(tp.north east)+(.5,.5)$);` et voilà.